# How to study the critical points of a $2$-variable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

I am revising some past exam questions and there is one that states:

> Study the critical points of the function:
>   $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-x^4-y^4-2x^2y^2.$$

According to my professor, this is what I have to do:

1. Find the gradient, which is $$\nabla f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix} 2x-4x^3-4xy^2 \\ 2y-4y^3-4x^2y \end{bmatrix}.$$
2. Find the Hessian, using partial derivatives, which is
   \begin{align*}
   f_{xx}(x,y) &= 2-12x^2-4y \\
   f_{xy}(x,y) &= -8xy \\
   f_{yx}(x,y) &= -8xy \\
   f_{yy}(x,y) &= 2-12y^2-4x^2.
   \end{align*}

And until here it's all good. However, what confuses me is the next step.

We need to search at first for $Cf$, the set of critical points of $f(x,y)$, so we have to impose $\nabla f(x,y) = 0$, namely
$$2x(1-2x^2-2y^2)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad 2y(1-2x^2-2y^2)=0.$$
And here I'm lost. On the answer sheet it states:
$$C*f*=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1/2\} \cup \{(0,0)\}.$$
What exactly does this property above mean? Where is the $x^2+y^2=1/2$ coming from and what does $\cup \{(0,0)\}$ mean? Is $\cup \{(0,0)\}$ the critical points, which are $0$?

Please explain in the clearest and simpelst way possible!

Note: this is the first part of the full question that I am interested in. As soon as I understand this, I will proceed with answering the full question.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cup$ means union.

From $$2x(1-2x^2-2y^2)=0 \iff 2x=0 \text{ or } 1-2x^2-2y^2=0$$
$$2y(1-2x^2-2y^2)=0 \iff 2y=0 \text{ or } 1-2x^2-2y^2=0$$

It is possible that $1-2x^2-2y^2=0 \iff x^2+y^2 = \frac12$.

Suppose not, then we must have $x=y=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! So this means that I the U(0,0) is coming from the 2x=0 and the 2y=0, and that the x^2+y^2=1/2 is coming from the 1-2x^2-2y^2, just by re-arranging the equation ? I'm sorry for the too many questions, I have dyscalculia and I need to get even the simplest things straight!

Comment: Yes, they come from those places that you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you !!! You are great!

Comment: May i ask you one last thing? What we wrote before implies that that the set of critical points of f(x, y) is given by the origin and the circle or radius √1/2 centered at the origin.  When it says to study the hessian at the origin, the matrix Hf(0,0) is a 2x2 matrix , with on top 2,0 and on botthom 0,2.... may i ask you where the 2's are coming from or is it a general formula?

Comment: The top $2$ at the bottom corresponds to computing $f_{xx}$ and evaluate it at $(0,0)$. The bottom $2$ corresponds to computing $f_{yy}$ and evaluate it at $(0,0)$.

Comment: While the 0's are just there because that's that?

Comment: those corresponds to $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$.

Comment: Again , thanks!!!!!!